# Node.js 404 when retrieving subroutes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make a node.js site that has multiple routers. The issue I am having is that the url `localhost:3000/forms/createForm` returns a 404 not found error. I'm pretty new to node so i am not 100% sure what to search for. I am also new to Stack overflow so if I have missed anything let me know :)

Note: my routers have been registered in my app.js file.

project structure:

```
app
|-routes
|    |-index.js
|    |-forms.js
|-views
     |-layout
     |-forms
         |-index.hbs
         |-createForm.hbs
```

Here is my forms.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('forms/index', { title: 'Forms' });
});

router.get('/createForm', function(req, res) {
    res.render('forms/createForm', { title: 'Create Form' })
});

module.exports = router;
```

And here is the server activity:

```
GET /forms/ 200 1.461 ms - 2480
GET /stylesheets/lightTheme.css 304 0.443 ms - -
GET /forms/createForm 404 5.085 ms - 4039
GET /stylesheets/lightTheme.css 304 0.508 ms - -
```

App.js:

```
var formsRouter = require('./routes/forms');
...
app.use('/forms', formsRouter);
```

Comment: Could you show the `app.js` file as well, please? Especially how you add/register the routers to your app.

Comment: Can you share `routes/index.js` and `app.js` which starts node, I think you're using `app.use('forms', routeForm)` `in index.js`. Is it correct?

Comment: As others have noted, it looks like you want to be navigating to `localhost:3000/createForm` in this case.  I just wanted to jump in and say that this error is related to the express.js library and note node itself.  The express.js documentation has a lengthy doc on routing you might be interested in: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Just added app.js code for the routers. My routes/index.js simply has a get method method for ‘/‘ as generated by Intelij Idea and that’s it. I am not sure if this approach is correct but attempted it as this project may get rather large in size and I wanted to seperate the code.

Answer (score 1):

You registered the `/createForm` route, not `/forms/createForm`. Also, you only have one router. If you wanted to use multiple routers, you could do:

```
var express = require('express');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var formsRouter = express.Router();
formsRouter.get('/createForm', function(req, res) {
    res.render('forms/createForm', { title: 'Create Form' })
});

var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('forms/index', { title: 'Forms' });
});

router.use('/forms', formsRouter);

module.exports = router;
```